# Azure Automation Runbook: Connect-AzAccount Error using Managed Identity

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

Looks like 'Run-as' accounts are retired, so I am trying to use Managed Identity to establish connection to my Azure resources in a Runbook (part of Azure Automation account).

I am following the instructions here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/add-user-assigned-identity#authenticate-access-with-user-assigned-managed-identity](https://stackoverflow.microsoft.com)

**Code**

```
$azureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -Tenant $tenantId -AccountId $managedIdentityApplicationId).context  # Connect to Azure with user-assigned managed identity
$connectionResult = Set-AzContext -Tenant $tenantId -Subscription $subscriptionId -DefaultProfile $azureContext
```

For `$managedIdentityApplicationId`, I am passing in the `ClientId` of the User-assigned Managed identity

**Error**

```
Connect-AzAccount : ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: **User assigned identity is currently not supported**
clientID must not be passed in request. 
Status: 400 (Bad Request)
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: `Connect-AzAccount -Identity` is all you need to connect using the AA managed Identity. Remove the extra parameters.

Comment: You're right. I figured out that only System-assigned managed identity can be used when running the Runbook for a Hybrid Worker. Using User-assigned Managed Identity only works when running the Runbook on Azure Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly, to connect Az account using managed identities, it is possible to use system assigned as well as user assigned managed identities.*

***System assigned identity:***

I Created a new automation account and runbook. Now go to `Identity` under `Account settings` and enable System assigned as shown.

[image]

Now to make it work without errors, you need to give a permission called `Automation Contributor` by clicking on the `Azure role assignments` in the above snap.

[image]

After its done, now you will be able to connect the Az account with the identity argument as shown below.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
```

*Output:*

[image]

***User assigned identity:***

Now I created a user assigned identity to connect Az account from automation runbook.

[image]

Here you need to enable `User Access Administrator role` for managing user access to Azure resources.

[image]

Referring to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/add-user-assigned-identity#authenticate-access-with-user-assigned-managed-identity) provided by you, I tried to execute the below given script in my runbook and was able to perform it successfully.

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$context = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "xxx").context
$context = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $context
write-output "context is $context"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions, Jahnavi. I tested it with System-assigned managed identity and it worked! I noticed that only System-assiend Managed identity can be used when running the Runbook on a Hybrid Worker. Using User-assigned Managed Identity only works when running the Runbook on Azure Cloud.

Comment: Both identities can be used to run the runbook irrespective of Hybrid worker. @thedataguy